# Black pine bonsai seedling

Tags: bonsai, pines

I just got a black pine seed to sprout and was wondering if I need to move it inside for the winter since it will be so young.

Comment: how cold is your winter?  Please provide a location and temperature range.  If you store it in a sheltered location that would be a good detail to add.

Answer (score 2):

[Japanese Black Pine (Pinus thunbergii)](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=557162323&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS920US920&sxsrf=AB5stBjvj3LbJBPZ_Wwnlamr6VzQsf3hBA:1692120973329&q=black+pine+bonsai&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT0KDsmd-AAxVQm4kEHcd7AocQ0pQJegQIDxAB&biw=1303&bih=659&dpr=1#imgrc=ueXfq0fUuF2YxM) is a very hardy tree down to -10F that will not only survive winters easily, but grow twice as ruggedly outdoors.

One technique is to leave it in the ground without worrying about root pruning, but prune the top hard at 4-6" to immediately train your baby to branch low and take on the posture of age.

You must know that bonsai from seed is a plan that you will be around for a long, long time.

[image: Japanese Black Pine]